# LunchList Android App

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Programming. I am doing this project from the book. I wrote the class to return the name and the address and then wrote the OnClickListener for it but it doesn't seem to work when i click the save Button. Here is my Two Java file:

```
package com.example.lunchlist;

public class Returant {

        private String name="";
        private String address="";
        public String getName() {
        return(name);
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        }
        public String getAddress() {
        return(address);
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address=address;
        }
        }
```

Here is my MainActivity File:

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Returant r = new Returant();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
        }

    private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
        r.setName(name.getText().toString());
        r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
        }

    };  
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to work when i click the save Button" -- what does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: I believe once you click the save Button it suppose to return the name and the address that you have on the TextField and it doesn't do anything on my Android Virtual Device.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe once you click the save Button it suppose to return the name and the address that you have on the TextField

I have no idea why you would think that. The book certainly does not indicate that. I know this, because I wrote the book in question. Specifically, this would appear to be from my retired book, *Android Programming Tutorials*, specifically Tutorial #2.

In [the most recent Creative Commons edition of the book (Version 3.4)](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/AndTutorials-3_4-CC.pdf), the end of the tutorial steps for Tutorial #2 has:

> Run the application to make sure it seems like it runs without errors,
>   though at this point we are not really using the data saved in the restaurant
>   object just yet.

All we are doing, at this point in the tutorials, is taking data out of `EditText` objects and putting it into a `Restaurant` (or, in your case, `Returant`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just log the value and see the log.
Try adding these two lines in the OnClickListener.

```
Log.i(TAG, r.getName());
Log.i(TAG, r.getAddress());
```

If something is printed out, that means you successfully set the values to the variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Returant r = new Returant();
EditText name;
EditText address;
String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
    }

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    r.setName(name.getText().toString());
    r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG, r.getName());
    Log.i(TAG, r.getAddress());
    }
};  
}
```

Comment: I seen what you're saying. Thanks a million for you help.

Comment: Is the Log.i suppose to return the value in my EditText because still when i click the Submit nothing happens. I know what i am trying to do if i was doing it in just java it would be so much easier. I haven't gone through the whole book yet but i just wanted to see how simple it is to do that. if you can show me an example or point me to one it will be helpful. I just started android programming since yesterday so i am totally new to this. Thanks

Comment: @ReazurRahman You can think of Log.i and System.out.println in Java. The value will printout in the Logcat area. If you haven't used logcat before you can try googling how to use it. Let me know if you get it.

Comment: I mean u can think of Log.i as System.out.println in Java.